# Taxonomy vocabulary in breadcrumbs / url

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

I have a menu with some items that link to some views which filter content type associated with vocabulary terms.

**Navigation**

```
Menu ITEM -> views page vocabulary
```

**Result** :

```
my-site.com/vocabulary
```

(here it’s the vocabulary i added `in view / PAGE SETTINGS / path` so it is not automatically generated from vocabulary)

When i click on on one of the articles, i can see the full content.

It works fine.

**Navigation** :

```
Menu ITEM -> views page vocabulary -> article
```

**Result** :

```
my-site.com/title-of-article
```

My question is related to breadcrumb.

The native breadcrumb of Drupal 8 doesn’t work properly. I’ve made a lot of search and discover that breadcrumb is not perfect in Drupal 8.

So I have tested 2 modules : [Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) and [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb)

Then, i can now display the Breadcrumb but i don’t see the taxonomy vocabulary in it.

I have :

```
home / Title of article
```

I would like to have

```
home / vocabulary / Title of article
```

or

```
home / (path view) / Title of article
```

I’ve sen other modules but they are not ported to D8 for now :

- [Taxonomy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb) (No further development)
- [Hansel          breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/hansel) (not D8)

How can I handle this ? Do I have to create a custom module to handle vocabulary terms in breadcrumb and in url ?

Comment: When you sync breadcrumbs and paths with Pathauto, so that each part of the path resolves to a route, then Drupal 8 builds the breadcrumbs automatically. Otherwise you need a contrib or custom breadcrumb builder module or add the missing breadcrumbs in a preprocess hook in theming if you don't want to use a module.

Comment: @4k4 Thank for the suggestions. I searched for a D8 contrib but didn’t found (for D7, there is a large choice). I’m going to dig "preprocess hook" or the custom module. Could you please explain what you means by "sync breadcrumbs and paths with Pathauto,". In pathauto, iI only see `[node:title]` pattern possible for content (no token for taxonomy).

Comment: It's hard to explain this more, in D8 the breadcrumbs are built according to the path structure. You only have to make sure, that all path components resolve to a route (test this in the browser by removing /xyz from the end of the path one by one and see if you still get a page and not a 404). About Pathauto, you should see more tokens than only one.

Comment: @4k4 I see more tokens but no token to build a correct path based on "view page path". I'll check again. I understand what you explain about route. I need to have correct path in order to build a correct breadcrumb and also to know where is user. For now, it’s like content has no hierarchy.

Comment: If all paths of a content type point to the same view, than you can use a fixed path component `/view-page-path/`. You only need a token, if this depends on a node field.

Comment: @4k4Yes, i can set a path pattern with pathauto but all paths of a same content type could point to different views (based on taxonomy). That' s why it is not so easy to have a working breadcrumb in this case.

Comment: Still this is more a path building problem You could use a custom token for this.

Comment: You’re right. That’s why in my question I also mention path but I was too focus on breadcrumb. If path/url to "view / content" reflects the correct hierarchy, breadcrumb will work with module like Easy Breadcrumb which uses the current URL (path alias). I’m working on it !